# Resume btrfs balance after interruption due to ENOSPC

Tags: linux, raid, btrfs

I'm building RAID5 out of 3 devices (3.7TB each). I run:

`btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid5 -mconvert=raid5 /mnt/storage0`

and it did process 3471 out of 3472 (sic!) chunks after which it failed with ENOSPC error.

`/mnt/storage0` was previously a RAID0 volume composed of 2 devices (again, 3.7TB each, I then added thrird drive). I freed some space from the volume and started the process again. Unfortunately it'll take two days for it to complete and I'm wondering if there's better way of doing it? Is it possible to somehow resume `btrfs balance -mconvert -dconvert` after it had failed due to ENOSPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this won't help you now (as you probably have dealt with the problem already) but, as others may look for an answer:
https://man.archlinux.org/man/btrfs.5.en#FILESYSTEM_WITH_MULTIPLE_PROFILES gives answer to your question:

```
It is possible that a btrfs filesystem contains multiple block group profiles of the same type. This could happen when a profile conversion using balance filters is interrupted (see btrfs-balance(8)). Some btrfs commands perform a test to detect this kind of condition and print a warning like this:

WARNING: Multiple block group profiles detected, see 'man btrfs(5)'.
WARNING:   Data: single, raid1
WARNING:   Metadata: single, raid1

The corresponding output of btrfs filesystem df might look like:

WARNING: Multiple block group profiles detected, see 'man btrfs(5)'.
WARNING:   Data: single, raid1
WARNING:   Metadata: single, raid1
Data, RAID1: total=832.00MiB, used=0.00B
Data, single: total=1.63GiB, used=0.00B
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=8.00MiB, used=112.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=64.00MiB, used=32.00KiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=16.25MiB, used=0.00B

There's more than one line for type Data and Metadata, while the profiles are single and RAID1.

This state of the filesystem OK but most likely needs the user/administrator to take an action and finish the interrupted tasks. This cannot be easily done automatically, also the user knows the expected final profiles.

In the example above, the filesystem started as a single device and single block group profile. Then another device was added, followed by balance with convert=raid1 but for some reason hasn't finished. Restarting the balance with convert=raid1 will continue and end up with filesystem with all block group profiles RAID1.

NOTE:
If you're familiar with balance filters, you can use convert=raid1,profiles=single,soft, which will take only the unconverted single profiles and convert them to raid1. This may speed up the conversion as it would not try to rewrite the already convert raid1 profiles.

Having just one profile is desired as this also clearly defines the profile of newly allocated block groups, otherwise this depends on internal allocation policy. When there are multiple profiles present, the order of selection is RAID56, RAID10, RAID1, RAID0 as long as the device number constraints are satisfied.

Commands that print the warning were chosen so they're brought to user attention when the filesystem state is being changed in that regard. This is: device add, device delete, balance cancel, balance pause. Commands that report space usage: filesystem df, device usage. The command filesystem usage provides a line in the overall summary:

Multiple profiles:                 yes (data, metadata)
```

So long story short: your disk is now in a state where some files were spread properly across disks, and some not. You may rerun balance with `convert=raid5,profiles=single,soft` which will cause only files with `single` profile (which refers to files not converted into raid5) to be converted into raid5.

Also mind, that raid5 is not recommended, especially for metadata.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think it's unclear. It provides more information than I expected. Dealing with data stored on RAID should not be dumbed down, the user should be expected to read and understand the provided information.